# Android растягивающийся widget в центре экрана

Tags: android, ui

вопрос в том как сделать виджет на экране который будет сам подстраиваться под размеры экрана. Например вверху есть элемент с заданой высотой, снизу тоже. По центру должен быть элемент который займет все оставшееся место. 
Вот мой код, не могу понять как растянуть правильно этот грид `<GridView android:id="@+id/TransitionTable">`

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/black"
    >
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:columnWidth="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp" 
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

</GridView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_prev"
        android:background="@drawable/greenbutton"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:text="@string/ButtonBack" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:background="@drawable/greenbutton"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:text="@string/ButtonForward" />

</LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/TransitionTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:padding="0dp" >

</GridView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStartPause"
        android:background="@drawable/greenbutton"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:text="@string/ButtonStart" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStop"
        android:background="@drawable/greenbutton"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:text="@string/ButtonStop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

</LinearLayout>

Comment: Используйте `RelativeLayout` и атрибуты `android:layout_below` и `android:layout_above` для элемента по центру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Откажитесь от вложенных LinearLayout. Забудьте про эту идею навсегда!
2. Используйте RelativeLayout для вложенных элементов(в ДАННОМ случае), которые будут зависеть от верхнего и нижнего(layout_above, layout_below-атрибуты) или в качестве корневого в любом другом макете.
3. GridView задайте со следующими параметрами в ширину - match_parent, в высоту - wrap_content или match_parent, экспериментируйте.
4. Подумайте как можно упростить верстку и идею.